# Mock Locations Automatically Turn Off

Tags: developer-tools

For some odd reason, when i enter developer options and switch on my mock locations, it automatically turns off. I don't know the reason for this and have thoroughly researched this and I have found nothing that helps me. I really need help for this...

Comment: i have same issue. what device do u use?

Comment: i think i found a solution. before that i need to know if your phone is rooted?